# How can I access property of instance already created

Tags: swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainViewController())
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }


class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var mainTV : UITableView = {
        let tv = UITableView()
        tv.delegate = self
        tv.dataSource = self
        tv.register(MainTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        tv.rowHeight = 1000  // property to access
        return tv
    }()
}



extension SubCollectionViewCell: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = todoTV.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! TodoTableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = todoList[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0


        if indexPath.row == todoList.count - 1 {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, animations: {
                self.todoTV.layoutIfNeeded()
            }) { (complete) in
                var heightOfTableView: CGFloat = 55.0
                let cells = self.todoTV.visibleCells
                for cell in cells {
                    heightOfTableView += cell.frame.height
                }
                //In here, I wanna access property of instance already created (MainViewController.mainTV.rowHeight)
            }
        }


        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you even want to do that kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
            let vc = MainViewController()
            let rowHeight = vc.mainTV.rowHeight
```

Comment: I'd like to approach the properties of the MainViewController instance already created in the Appdelegate and change the value.

Comment: I'm not sure why would you want to do something like that, but if you want to access the AppDelegate from a view controller you can make an instance of it like this :     `let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate`

Comment: The code you gave me was to create a new instance of MainViewController and change the property value. I want to access the instance of MainViewController created when the app is first run.

Comment: This is for MainViewController's dynamic row height.

Answer (score 0):

When you call lazy variable property, it is initialize instance of your tableView.

- I think you should create instance of tableView as a global variable like this:

  ```
  class MainViewController: UIViewController {

      lazy var mainTV : UITableView = {
          let mainTableView = UITableView()
          mainTableView.delegate = self
          mainTableView.dataSource = self
          mainTableView.register(MainTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
          mainTableView.rowHeight = 1000
          return tv
      }()
  }
  ```
- And then (in cellForRowAt function):

  ```
  mainTableView.rowHeight = 12345
  ```

I hope this answer works for you.

**edit:** If you want to create Table View with dynamic row height you should set;

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight // whatever you want
tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```